# Does datagrip have the same SSH session function as pycharm?

Tags: pycharm, datagrip

In the pycharm terminal plugin, I can create an SSH session to log in to the server remotely. Is there a similar function in Datagrip? According to the official Datagrip documentation, The Terminal plugin is not bundled with DataGrip, so I downloaded the plugin and installed it manually. But only local sessions can be created (Windows PowerShell and CMD), so how to create remote sessions?[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

You can install Terminal plugin in settings:
[image]